# Is there @minApi annotation, analogous to @TargetApi annotation in Android?

Tags: android, android-annotations

```
int API_VERSION = 21;
```

@TargetApi(API_VERSION) is used in Android to specify that the method/class is supported for API_VERSION and below.

Can we mirror something similar which specifies that a method or class is supported for API_VERSION and above only?

Note:- I did not find any such annotation, but would like to ask the community if they have come across something like this or have implemented their own annotation?

Comment: What do you expect the effect of this annotation to be? The point behind annotations is to have compile-time or runtime effects.

Comment: @CommonsWare I want the particular class/method to be called only on higher API Levels. This class/method uses Higher API Levels, say 21 and above. For eg, using material design for 21+, but not calling this on lower levels. nhaarman has a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`@RequiresApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RequiresApi.html):

> Denotes that the annotated element should only be called on the given API level or higher.
>
> This is similar in purpose to the older @TargetApi annotation, but more clearly expresses that this is a requirement on the caller, rather than being used to "suppress" warnings within the method that exceed the minSdkVersion.

Comment: Awesome. Just what I needed.